# Make .asm files in a folder as JMenuItems and add them to a JMenu, add ActionListener Events

Tags: java, swing, file, jmenu, jmenuitem

lets say I have a folder called `examples/basics/`
In that folder I have a bunch of .asm files. What I would now like to do is to have those files automatically made into JMenuItems, without the .asm extension, placed inside a JMenu and have actionlisteners added to them, that do the following:

> User clicks on JMenuItem genetated.  A new, lets say a CodeArea object is created and the file *examples/basics/what I clikced on* is passed in as a new File.

How to achive this with the simplest means?

Comment: What's your problem, it's not clear. You can't iterate all files in folder and create Menu dinamycally? or you can't create `ActionListener` that create new `File` from path?

Comment: Read all fileNames in that directory with the right extension and store them in an array or list. Iterate over that list and create one menuItem per iteration with the current name and add it to your menuBar and also add an actionListener.

Comment: How do I make the read loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example for your purposes:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu);

    JMenu mainMenu = new JMenu("Menu");
    menu.add(mainMenu);

    File f = new File(PATH_TO_FOLDER);
    if(f.exists()){
        File[] listFiles = f.listFiles();
        for(File file : listFiles){
            if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(EXTENSION)){
                final JMenuItem m = new JMenuItem(file.getName());
                mainMenu.add(m);
                m.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        System.out.println(m.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Here **PATH_TO_FOLDER** is path to your folder with files

**EXTENSION** is target extension of file for menus

Comment: Maybe , but I prefer to use separate listener for buttons and same code decorate as method.